# How can I make a button redirect you in HTML?

Tags: html

I have been curious about the `<button>` attribute. I can't seem to get it to work like `<a>` attributes. What do I mean by that? Well, I can do `<a href="url">Link</a>` to redirect you. But you can't do that with `<button>`. How can I make a button do the same?

Comment: `<button onclick="location.href = 'NEW_URL_HERE';">redirect</button>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: You can look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/2906582/1047998

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
<button onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com/';">Go There!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can attach a button to a form and have it submit it which will load the page.

```html
<form id="xxx" action="https://www.stackoverflow.com"></form>


<button form="xxx">Go now!</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try setting the `<a>` inside the `<button>` like this

```
<button>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/">Salir</a>
</button>
```